# How to disable creating default value by jscolor and how to add 'transparent' value

Tags: jscolor

When I set empty value in input, a jscolor inserts unwanted FFFFFF.

Second: Is it possible to jscolor returning transparent?

Answer (score 2):

**First**

I was able to set the jscolor labels with this:

```
$('#your-jscolor-element').val(elementColored.style.backgroudColor);
```

Note: I was using  elements.

**Second**

I haven't found a way to use jscolor with transparency. So I used a workaround of creating a button to remove the color from the element that the particular jscolor instance was modifying. I suppose if you are getting color in rgb, maybe you can get those RGB values and then use them to write 'rgba('+yourR+','+'yourG'+','+yourB+','+'0.2)' to the element's style rule.